# how to identify and download images in telehton newMessage event?

Tags: python, telethon

I wrote a simple python script to save all messages seen by a user to files using an telethon event handler:

```py
@CLIENT.on(events.NewMessage)

async def my_event_handler(event):
    sender = await event.get_sender()
    chat_id = event.chat_id

    out ='\n\n' +  sender.username + ': ' + event.text + ' [' + str(chat_id) + ']'
    name = hashlib.sha1(out.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

    outdir = ECHODIR + '/' + str(chat_id)

    f_h = open(outdir + '/' + name, 'a')
    f_h.write(out)
    f_h.close()

CLIENT.start()
CLIENT.run_until_disconnected()
```

how can I detect that an image is received and download the image from the event?

*p.s. removed unnecessary code, e.g. to check if dir exist*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Objects Reference summary for `Message`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/objects-reference.html#message), the [`message.photo`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.message.Message.photo) property will be "The [Photo](https://tl.telethon.dev/?q=Photo) media in this message, if any.".

This means that, to detect an image (or photo) in your code you can do:

```
if event.photo:
    ...
```

The [`Message` methods](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/objects-reference.html#methods) also contains a [`message.download_media()`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.message.Message.download_media) such that:

```
saved_path = await event.download_media(optional_path)
```

Comment: so in my case the event object is a message object and I can use all message methods.

Comment: Yes, the `NewMessage.Event` can be treated *as if* it were a `Message` object, and it's the recommended way to use it. If you want to avoid using the `event` proxy, you can also do `event.message` to access the actual `Message` object.

Comment: This downloads a thumb only. Is there a way to download the full image?

Comment: It should be downloading the entire photo, for reference, https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/1672.